# how to call a ion-select when clicked on a ion-card

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am setting up a page in ionic web app, where a  should appear upon when a ion-card is clicked. My ion-select is pure html.

Tried adding a method, but how to add this html in that .ts file so that i can do (click)="doSomething()"

```
<ion-card>
   <ion-card-header> Header </ion-card-header>
</ion-card>


<ion-list>
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Hair color</ion-label>
  <ion-select value="brown" okText="OK" cancelText="Cancel">
    <ion-select-option> Black </ion-select-option>                                 
    <ion-select-option> Brown </ion-select-option>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

i want that ion-list to display upon clicking the ion-card

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by binding your `<ion-card-header>` with the click event, and then adding the `*ngIf` structural directive on your `<ion-list>`

```
<ion-card>
   <ion-card-header (click)="onClick()"> Header </ion-card-header>
</ion-card>


<ion-list *ngIf="displayList">
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Hair color</ion-label>
  <ion-select value="brown" okText="OK" cancelText="Cancel">
    <ion-select-option> Black </ion-select-option>                                 
    <ion-select-option> Brown </ion-select-option>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

On your component.ts, onClick will assign `true` to `displayList`, which will display the `ion-list` when the header is clicked.

```
displayList: boolean = false;

onClick() {
  this.displayList = true;
}
```

I have forked a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-sample-my3w8b?file=pages/home/home.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did work for a certain level. Right now, a label is being displayed and if i click that then ion-select is being displayed. Like in the demo you provided, after clicking header it opens a list named hair color and upon clicking on that a select box appears. How can i get the select box right after clicking the header? Thanks again.

Comment: @RohitBattepati In that case, you will need to open the `ion-select` programatically. I have recreated an updated demo over here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-sample-evpfjg?file=pages/home/home.ts
Let me know if it makes sense to you?

Comment: Yes this is what i needed, thanks. Anyway we can make the hair color label not to display?  and directly displaly the box when clicked on header?

Comment: @RohitBattepati Hmm.. If you don't want the label to show, maybe you can remove the entire label?

Comment: Yes, tried it. It is just removing the label and displaying an empty line. when i click on that then the select box appears.

Comment: @RohitBattepati I see.. Maybe you can use CSS to 'hide' it?